# Why commit updates are shown in main folder and not in master branch? Xcode

Tags: xcode, version-control, bitbucket

I just did two commits and they don't show up on master branch, they do in the main project folder, same in Bitbucket repo, it only shows yesterdays commits.  I'm not sure how to fix this. If I try to check out to master branch, I get a warning to lighter push or discard changes, but if I push them, they don't appear anywere. I'd appreciate very much a little explanation on how that could have occurred. I'm just starting with version control and I surely messed it up when I checked out on previous commits to check some part of the code, although I thought I did check-out again on last commit. 
Many thanks as usual.

[image: showin commits on main folder.]

[image]

Comment: @shup thanks for the edits I didn't see the misspelled words

Answer (score 2):

I solved it as so:

1. Selected the latest commit on actual Master branch.
2. Created a new branch from it and named it anything but Master. That is an exact copy of actual non synchronised Master branch.
3. Deleted actual Master branch.
4. Created a new branch from latest commit on newer created branch at point 2 and named it Master.
5. Deleted branch created at step 2.
6. Pushed the missing commits to Bitbucket.
7. Now I have a new Master branch that is in sync with its bucket.

Hope this will help others.

Comment: when you get chance it would be useful for others to elaborate on how you did step 3 :-)

Comment: @nc14 I updated my answer with a clearer step-by-step guide. Hope it's clearer. Don't hesitate to comment if you have any problem following it , and I'll guide you. Cheers.

Comment: @nc14 i'm i could help ;)